# How to create zip archive without ini and zip files

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a folder which contain :

```
bd.txt
/Config
/DLL
/Rapports
bx1478.ini
ARCH.zip
```

I want to create an archive without ini and zip files.
I try as below but i get an empty archive :

```
import subprocess
SZ_PATH_TMP = '../tmp'
SZ_PATH_WORK = '../work'
full_label_version = 'ARCH' 
subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', SZ_PATH_TMP+'/'+full_label_version+'.zip', SZ_PATH_WORK+'/* -xr!*.zip -xr!*.ini'])
```

Comment: You are using relative paths. Are you sure they are correct and that you are running your python script from the correct location. Try setting the working directory for the subprocess call to the appropriate directory.

Comment: Yes the relative paths work fine because when i delete -xr!*.zip -xr!*.ini, the generation works but with all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a list of arguments to `subprocess`, each option needs to be a separate list item.

```py
import subprocess
SZ_PATH_TMP = '../tmp'
SZ_PATH_WORK = '../work'
full_label_version = 'ARCH' 
subprocess.call(
    ['7z', 'a', 
    SZ_PATH_TMP+'/'+full_label_version+'.zip',
    SZ_PATH_WORK+'/*,  '-xr!*.zip', '-xr!*.ini'])
```

If you don't know exactly how the shell breaks the command line up into arguments, maybe pass the entire command as a string to `shlex.split()`

Comment: If you're on Windows, I'm not sure `shlex` works correctly there. (Maybe "correctly" isn't even well-defined on Windows.)